# How to get the user information who are not in my roster list?

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework, rosters

I am working on group chat using robbiehanson/XMPPFramework. I have done sending invitation,accepting invitation and messaging in group chat. 
Here I want to show some information of user who sent message in group chat including his avatar. 
I can get the users information from **XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject**. this case is applicable only if those users are present in my friend list. I need to get the users information who are not in my friend list. Is there any possible way to achieve this. Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

In XMPP, avatar (vcard) of any user can be fetched irrespective of roster entries. So if you are trying to query vcard of any other user of your service, then it should work. If it's not working, please provide the both "get" and "result" IQ here for vcard request.

However, if you are trying to query presence status of other user's then yes there is restriction of roster. This can be overcome by implementing following logic:

- User registers in your application (Android or iPhone), determine registered contacts of your service from user contact book and automatically add them in your roster.
- Also Implement roster request handling in your application that when it get's request for allowing other user to add you in his roster, automatically accept the request and send request to that user to add him in your roster too.
- Now again accept that request.

In this way, you can add users in roster behind the scenes and user's can view the information of other users just like WhatsApp.

Comment: But thing is that in my app I want to show roster list to whom i have sent and accept the request. This thing i cant put in black box from the user :)

Comment: Then for custom requirements, you can perform some modifications in openfire code and roster list check can be commented. As openfire is opensource, so we can perform custom changes and build the project.

Comment: Yeah looking on the same . Thanks for your message :)